AWS EMR Jupyter Notebook not saving '_xsrf' argument missing from POST
In AWS EMR the Jupyter Notebook won't even attach to a cluster without giving the error:
'_xsrf' argument missing from POST

A lot of the solutions I have tried such as refreshing the page when directing back to the base folder, or trying to open another notebook on the same kernel then going back do not work. Not sure if this is because it is in AWS EMR or not, but the solutions I have found online don't seem to translate to this environment.
On other notebooks I also cannot attach the kernel (PySpark if it matters) and get the same error. Any help is appreciated!
